# Less verbose way to do lazy loading

Tags: java, lazy-loading

I am refactoring a class called `ConfigNode` that stores 50 "properties". Each property is an object of its own. All properties are optional, and most of the time, many of them are not set.

Currently, the class is written so that when it is instantiated, all 50 properties are instantiated as well. When you create a million `Config` objects, Java tells me I'm using 2.5 gigs of memory. When I comment out the property instantiation, Java says I'm using 300 MB.

The benchmark code I'm using is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
// do my stuff
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
long memory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
System.out.println("Memory used: " + memory / 1000000 + " MB");
```

So I'm thinking of rewriting the class to lazy load a property when it's accessed, but having to write something like

```
// This is probably not thread safe, so it could be even more verbose
public NodeProperty propOne() {
   if (propOne == null) {
      propOne = new NodeProperty( ... )
   }
   return propOne
}
```

And then do it for all of the properties seems kind of verbose. Is there anything in Java that can help me reduce the amount of code I have to write (and consequently, maintain)?

Here is how the NodeConfig looks like

```
public class NodeConfig {

    public NodeProperty pVersion = new NodeProperty( "Spec Version", Status.REQUIRED, Visibility.HIDDEN);
    public NodeProperty pTwoWay = new NodeProperty( "Two way", Status.OPTIONAL, Visibility.VISIBLE );
    public NodeProperty pBinary = new NodeProperty( "Binary mode", Status.OPTIONAL, Visibility.HIDDEN);

    // more properties

    public NodeConfig() {
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: "all 50 properties are instantiated as well" -- could you modify this constructor so that instead of instantiating objects that you simply store null if the property does not exist or is not to be used?

Comment: `totalMemory()` may not be doing exactly what you think it is - "the total amount of memory currently available for current **and future** objects, measured in bytes." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory())

Comment: Only idea I have is maybe something with reflection.  Try write one method for all 50 calls.  Other than that, try refactoring your object.  If there are many properties its not using, that's a sign it has too much state, too much responsibility.

Comment: My "answer" wasn't really going to work.  It would help if we saw the structure of the NodeProperty type and how ConfigNode references them.

Comment: I've added an example of how it looks with a couple sample properties.

Comment: Lazy loading will not solve your memory issue; it will delay it.  Assuming that you need a million config objects, then you really need 2.5gig of memory to hold them.  For memory constraints, consider the flyweight pattern.

Comment: @DwB For certain applications, any properties that aren't used, do not need to be instantiated. I imagine there should be considerable savings here. For other applications, they will instantiate everything. Perhaps I can consider both lazy loading and the flyweight pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**
Here's another approach you could use given the `NodeConfig` code: 
    public class NodeConfig {

```
    public NodeProperty pTwoWay;
    public NodeProperty pBinary;

    // more properties

    public NodeConfig() {
        // 
    }

    public NodeProperty getProperty(NodePropertyEnum nodeProp) {
        switch(nodeProp) {
            case TWO_WAY: 
                if (pTwoWay != null) {return pTwoWay;}
                pTwoWay = new NodeProperty( "Two way", Status.OPTIONAL, Visibility.VISIBLE ); 
            case BINARY_MODE: 
                if (pBinary != null) {return pBinary;}
                pBinary = new NodeProperty( "Binary mode", Status.OPTIONAL, Visibility.VISIBLE); 
            // other cases
            default: 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**
Looks like a case for `Singleton` design pattern. Rather than checking for `propOne` instance to be `null`, it will be better if you make all Property classes singleton. Something like:

```
public class NodeProperty {

    private static volatile NodeProperty instance = null;

    private NodeProperty() {
        // instantiatin logic
    }

    public NodeProperty getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(NodeProperty.class) {
                if(instance==null) {
                    instance = new NodeProperty();
                }
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `instance` needs to be `volatile` for double-checked locking to be correct.

Comment: To improve approach-1, you could use a LRU cache (LinkedHasMap) implementation with a cap of say 10, that way you system will automagically keep on dropping off properties that are not used, bringing down the memory foot-print of your class.

Answer (score 2):

Guava's [Suppliers](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html) library can do all the logic of lazy-loading for you (including thread-safety, which your example doesn't have).

```
import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import com.google.common.base.Suppliers;

private Supplier<NodeProperty> propOneSupplier =
    Suppliers.memoize(() -> new NodeProperty(...));

public NodeProperty propOne() {
    return propOneSupplier.get();
}
```